# What is the purpose of this SQL syntax (AS XYZ NUMBER)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm studying this PL/SQL code, and the beginning section looks like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PARTY.ADELS_SPROC_NAME(
    p_batch_mod_ind IN VARCHAR2,
    .../*etc etc */

  )

AS tmpVar NUMBER;
```

I don't see what the

```
AS tmpVar NUMBER;
```

section is doing ? What is this for?

Comment: It's all in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS1527

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AS` (or `IS`) indicates the beginning of your declarations section.  Within your declarations section, you are declaring a local variable `tmpVar` of type `NUMBER`.  Normally, you'd have multiple variables declared in your declarations section.  Your procedure skeleton is something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE <<procedure name>> (
  <<list of parameters>>
)
AS
  <<declare local variables>>
BEGIN
  <<do something>>
END <<procedure name>>;
```

The `AS` has nothing directly to do with the subsequent declaration.